# Input Checkbox Only Updates One Value But Other Inputs Don't Update?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input, checkbox

So I have this app I made where it calculates the menu items total and includes a $5 delivery fee. The problem is the 4th option only includes the $5 fee in the total, but the other 3 options don't include the fee

Here's my codepen
https://codepen.io/shodoro/pen/dydNopX

Why is my 4th option, the smoothie $4 the only input checkbox that adds the delivery fee correctly?

The first 3 options don't include the $5 delivery fee in the total and I don't know how to fix it

Here's my JS

```
      function updatePrice() {
          let items = 0;
          let deliveryFee = document.getElementById('fee')
          let tax = document.getElementById('tax')    
          let tip = document.getElementById('tip')

          tax = .1
          tip = .2

          document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(checkBox => {
              if (checkBox.checked) {
                  items += +checkBox.value
                  deliveryFee = 5
              } else {
                  deliveryFee = 0
              }
          })


          document.getElementById("price").textContent = `Food Total: $${(items).toFixed(2)}`;
          document.getElementById("tax").textContent = `Tax (10%): $${(items * tax).toFixed(2)}`;
          document.getElementById("tip").textContent = `Tip (20%): $${(items * tip).toFixed(2)}`;
          document.getElementById("total").textContent = `Your order total is: $${((items * tax)+(items * tip)+(items)+(deliveryFee)).toFixed(2)}`;
      }
```

Essential I want all options to include the delivery fee when clicking them, but also making sure the delivery fee resets to 0 whenever you uncheck all options.

Comment: you're simply setting the `deliveryFee` to either 0 or 5 for each of the checkboxes, overwriting any previous value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you are setting `deliveryFee` in a loop and so if, for example, the 12 piece wings item is checked, then it sets `deliveryFee` to 5 and then it's going to loop through to the next item (6 piece wings) and it will set `deliveryFee` to 0. So when it gets to the calculation for the total, it `deliveryFee` will be 0 and not 5. I think maybe you want something more like this:

```
          function updatePrice() {
              console.log('updatePrice');
              let items = 0;
              let deliveryFee = 0;
              let tax = document.getElementById('tax')    
              let tip = document.getElementById('tip')

              tax = .1
              tip = .2
              console.log('before forEach loop', items, deliveryFee);
              document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(checkBox => {
                  console.log(checkBox);
                  if (checkBox.checked) {
                      console.log('checked!')
                      items += +checkBox.value
                      if (deliveryFee == 0) {
                        console.log('First checked item, setting delivery fee to 5.')
                        deliveryFee = 5;
                      }
                  } else {
                    console.log('not checked!');
                  }
              })
              console.log('after forEach loop', items, deliveryFee);
            
              if (items >= 10) {
                deliveryFee = deliveryFee * 2;
              }

              let orderTotal = (items * tax)+(items * tip)+(items) + deliveryFee;

              document.getElementById("price").textContent = `Food Total: $${(items).toFixed(2)}`;
              document.getElementById("tax").textContent = `Tax (10%): $${(items * tax).toFixed(2)}`;
              document.getElementById("tip").textContent = `Tip (20%): $${(items * tip).toFixed(2)}`;
              document.getElementById("fee").textContent = `Delivery Fee: $${deliveryFee.toFixed(2)}`;
              document.getElementById("total").textContent = `Your order total is: $${orderTotal}`;
          }
```

Comment: ah I see. Do you know how I could make the delivery fee value change based on the total price of all the items? I tried to do `deliveryFee = checkBox.value * 2` for example, however if I choose menu item at $4 it will make the fee $8, but then right when I click another item at $3 it will convert the fee back to $6 instead of just doing $4 + $3 = $7 * 2 = $14. Ideally I would want to just use a percent but I just did x2 to make it easier to follow

Comment: I think you're still not quite following what happens when this function runs. You can use `console.log` statements to print out what's happening which can help you understand where the problem is. I've added some console log statements and also implemented your request that the delivery fee doubles if the cost of the items is $10 or greater.